# Is it possible, with Envoy Proxy, to apply an HTTP filter based on the URL?

Tags: envoyproxy

As the title says, I would like an HTTP filter to apply only if the request is for a certain URL path. Doing this at the route level is not possible, because my route is defined like this:

```yaml
- match:
    prefix: "/api/"
  route:
    cluster: some_backend_service
    prefix_rewrite: "/"
```

But I would like to apply different (security related) filters for `/api/foo` than for `/api/bar`. I can't seem to find a way to do this looking at the documentation, is it even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Composite Filter is exactly what you are looking for.
Please refer to this page:
https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/composite_filter.html
An example: 3 Lua filters are configured in a composite filter, they are adding a response header "triggered" of value "action-1" for /get/action1, "action-2" for /get/action2, "no-match" for other paths

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        protocol: TCP
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8080
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: upstream
                  timeout: 1s
                name: default_route
          http_filters:
          - name: composite
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.common.matching.v3.ExtensionWithMatcher
              extension_config:
                name: composite
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.composite.v3.Composite
              matcher:
                on_no_match:
                  action:
                    name: action-no-match
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.composite.v3.ExecuteFilterAction
                      typed_config:
                        name: envoy.filters.http.lua
                        typed_config:
                          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
                          inlineCode: |
                            function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                            end
                            function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
                              response_handle:headers():add("triggered", "no-match")
                            end
                matcher_list:
                  matchers:
                  - predicate:
                      single_predicate:
                        input:
                          name: "action1-matcher"
                          typed_config:
                            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.type.matcher.v3.HttpRequestHeaderMatchInput
                            header_name: :path
                        value_match:
                          prefix: /get/action1
                          ignore_case: true
                    on_match:
                      action:
                        name: composite-action-1
                        typed_config:
                          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.composite.v3.ExecuteFilterAction
                          typed_config:
                            name: envoy.filters.http.lua
                            typed_config:
                              "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
                              inlineCode: |
                                function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                                end
                                function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
                                  response_handle:headers():add("triggered", "action-1")
                                end
                  - predicate:
                      single_predicate:
                        input:
                          name: "action2-matcher"
                          typed_config:
                            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.type.matcher.v3.HttpRequestHeaderMatchInput
                            header_name: :path
                        value_match:
                          prefix: /get/action2
                          ignore_case: true
                    on_match:
                      action:
                        name: composite-action-2
                        typed_config:
                          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.composite.v3.ExecuteFilterAction
                          typed_config:
                            name: envoy.filters.http.lua
                            typed_config:
                              "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
                              inlineCode: |
                                function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                                end
                                function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
                                  response_handle:headers():add("triggered", "action-2")
                                end
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
  - name: upstream
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    connect_timeout: 
      seconds: 10
    type: STRICT_DNS
    transport_socket:
      name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
      typed_config:
        '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: upstream
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: httpbin.org
                port_value: 443
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
```

Comment: I've read the docs and at the moment they support only matching for HTTP headers. Can't find any way to match by URL prefix.

Comment: @MitchSitin I think you could try matching ":path" pseudo header

Comment: I am trying to get that work too, would either of you have their sample configs they could add to the accepted answer?