# Is it possible to filter local network traffic based on the URL?

Tags: nginx, networking, proxy, network-traffic, envoyproxy

What I'm planning to do is e.g. allow:  `https://website.com/a/` but block: `https://website.com/b/`.

Research on *proxy servers* seems like they  filter based on only domain names `website.com`. Since most request are encrypted (*https*), a proxy cannot view the *url*s.

What tool would allow me to do this?

In [this](https://serverfault.com/q/1089564/1070681) question they say can be done by *Envoy Proxy*, a want to be sure. Can be done by *nginx*?, would this be a reverse or forward proxy?

Comment: You can proxy some https connections if you install your own CA certificate to all clients that use the proxy, and use that CA to sign the site certificates used by nginx. However, if the destination web server uses HSTS public key pinning, then those sites cannot be proxied.

Comment: A FORWARD proxy is used near the browser end to manage the behaviour of a group of clients, e.g. within an organization. A reverse proxy is used near the origin server to manage the traffic regardless of where the client is connecting from. If by "local network traffic" you mean relating to local clients then you want a forward proxy. While both nginx and squid can perform either role, the former is best suited as a reverse proxy and the latter as a forward proxy. How you handle TLS traffic is a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a forward proxy, which can be done with nginx, or squid (amongst others).
There is a good post on how to do it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/nginx-forward-proxy) using nginx (which seems to be your preference), but the SSL component is a challenge.

There's a good pointer about squid [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731702/how-to-use-forward-proxy-for-https)

Other alternatives - privoxy is highly rated

Comment: So, it can be done what I'm looking for but using my own certificate, is that right?